# How to stop Emacs from using LaTeX mode key bindings for `*.tex` files?

Tags: latex, debugging, auto-mode-alist

It seems that Emacs tries to autodetect the type of file and changes some of its behaviors accordingly. I don't want any of this behavior. I just want Emacs to treat every file as if it were some generic text file. The thing that is currently annoying me is that when Emacs thinks I'm editing a LaTeX file, it won't let me type the `"` character without changing it to tex-style quotes. Is there a line I can put in my `.emacs` file to simply turn off all of this kind of stuff completely?

From googling, it looks like this is called an "input method," but the only lisp code I can find doesn't seem like it would do what I want. For example, there is a function called `set-input-mode`, but it doesn't seem to allow control over this. There are also things like `toggle-input-method` and `(setq-default default-input-method ...`, but those don't seem like what I'm looking for either.

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew: I do see the same problem if I use -Q. I think this is just generic behavior of emacs. It seems to be triggered by the fact that the filename ends in .tex.

Answer (score 2):

After some more googling, I think I found the answer to my own question. The following code works:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist ())
```

The list `auto-mode-alist` seems to be a hash that has file extensions as keys and major modes as values: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoModeAlist

Comment: I was just going to suggest that :-)

Comment: You should probably [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) your answer.